# Magento 2 - How to add Birthday field to Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, forms

I need to add the **birthday** field with a validation (which is activated from admin) in the checkout shipping form.

**I checked different templates in the checkout module but i cannot get it showing up.**

how to display Birthday field in checkout shipping form.

Thanks.

Comment: Dob is a customer attribute or customer address attribute?

Comment: i really cannot say, i think its related to the customer. what i want to do is to add the birthday select to the shipping form in checkout

Comment: as far as I know, the fields on checkout should belong to the customer address attributes (at least).

Comment: Yes, we can add the dob to checkout form(shipping step). However, I really want to know the purpose of this field - on the backend side?

Comment: ok, i have to check if the customer is older than 18 years (has to be older in order to purchase products in store). If not than they cannot continue the checkout process

Comment: just to clarify `dob` like email, firstname etc is part of `customer_entity` it is not related to any address the customer may have.